# Creating an HTML page from PHP

Tags: php, html

So I'm creating new HTML pages using PHP and I'm running into a problem.

```
<?php
$filecreate = $fopen("yo.html","w");
fwrite($filecreate,"<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad"></script>
....... </html>")
?>
```

It seems like It's maybe grabbing one of the quotes from the `<script src=` tag and ending it early. How would I get around this issue?

Comment: escape the double quotes properly

Comment: example instead of " use \"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the character you use as a string delimiter in the content of your string. The syntax highlighter in your IDE shows you that something's wrong.

Replace your double quotes inside your string with simple quotes, or escape them.

```
fwrite($filecreate,"<html>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad'></script>
....... </html>")
```

or

```
fwrite($filecreate,"<html>
<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>
<script src=\"http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad\"></script>
....... </html>")
```

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/../public_html/website/index.php on line 7

Comment: Ask a new question with this problem, and provide the relevant code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398902/fatal-error-function-name-must-be-a-string-in-home-user-public-html-website-in

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        $filecreate = $fopen("yo.html","w");
        fwrite($filecreate,"<html>
        <script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>
        <script src=\"http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad \"></script>
        ....... </html>")
        ?>
```

You have started a quote " and added another " on script, you should escape them