# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/User/public_html/website/index.php on line 7

Tags: javascript, php, html

The error code is in the question:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/User/public_html/website/index.php on line 7.

The first ~10 lines of PHP:

```
<?php
$filecreate = $fopen("y1o.html","w");
$text = "<html>
<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>
<script src=\"http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad\"></script>
<title>website</title>
<body> <- Line 7?
<iframe id=\"myYTPlayer\" width=\"640\" height=\"390\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"YouTube video player\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&controls=0\"></iframe>
<p id=\"timer\">0:00</p>
</body>
<script>
...JS code
</script>
</html>
?>
```

Comment: Remove that `$` in front of `fopen` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: ^^ Got it! That's it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be -

```
$filecreate = fopen("y1o.html","w");
```